# Exported .fbx not opening

Tags: export, import, .fbx

I have a rigged and animated file made in blender that was exported as a .fbx file, but I can't open it with FBX Review or Unity. There is no error message that show up in either tool.

I have no idea what the problem is. I did a lot of searching and reading still have no clue on what is happening. I can't reproduce the problem. It happened on this file only.
Any help is appreciated.

The file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1INcxwUYd8i0rmObaHUsYJz9C4VmVQsHJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi have you tried importing it back to blender itself? That worked alright for me.

Comment: yeah, i can import it back too. but still can't open it with unity or FBX Review.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason:

I didn't apply the modifier inside Blender, but applied it when exporting.
That's why it crashed. Just apply the modifier in Blender, before exporting, then everything is OK.